# React Native and lodash: Node has not been attached to a view?

Tags: react-native, redux, lodash, react-redux

I'm getting this error "Node has not been attached to a view" when I'm trying to open a page in my application.

I've found out what the problem is related to, but I can't seem to find a solution...
This is the code that makes the error appear:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    const adventures = state.adventures.localSavedAdventures;

    return {
        loading: state.adventures.loading,
        localSavedAdventures: _.map(adventures, (val, key) => { return { ...val, key } })
    };
}
```

The "adventures" object is not empty, so that should not be a problem. I got this code to work on an other page, so I really don't get what's wrong here. Lodash is installed and imported correctly. Does anyone see the problem?

Here is a screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the error with some debugging (yes I should have done that earlier...). My object is in fact not always an object, but can also be a string. Thus lodash throws an error.